# How to change the value of an attribute of a bean in list?

Tags: java, list, javabeans

I am having a list of bean, now i want to change the value of an attribute of all the beans in the list. For example:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    String attrXYZ;

    /* accessors and mutators */
}
```

---

```
List<Person> lstPerson = getAllPersons();
//set the attribute attrXYZ of all persons in the list to 'undefined'
```

One way is to iterate the list and call `setAttrXYZ ( 'undefined' );` this is what i am doing right now.
I would like to know is there any other approach of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the advantage of dynamic languages like groovy, where you could do this as a one-liner:

```
myList.each{ it.setAttrXYZ ( 'undefined' ) }
```

In java, the shortest way is either to use java 5 loops or iterators:

```
for(MyBean bean : list){
    bean.setAttrXYZ ( "undefined" );
}
```

or

```
Iterator<MyBean> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    it.next().setAttrXYZ("undefined");
}
```

(both of which is pretty much the same thing internally)

Comment: No matter the amount of syntactic sugar or dynamic code you throw at it, it still is just a simple loop over the list applying some code to each element.

Comment: internally, yes. But for the developer it can be a question of: "do I really want to go through all this trouble?" vs. "hey, not a problem". (Not in this trivial case of course)

Comment: woa, i like that one liner groovy code[ even if it is not in java ] :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, even using reflection, you would have to iterate over your list. As a consequence, as far as I know, there is no other solution to that.